# App loads with white screen for 3 secs before showing proper UI - using fragments (no webview)

Tags: android

I've made a brand new Android project using the new project wizard in Eclipse:

**Step 1: new project properties**

- Min API: 16
- Max API: 19
- Theme: **Holo Dark**
- Create Activity -> Navigation type: Action Bar Tabs (with ViewPager)

**Step 2: update `/res/activity_main.xml` to show a black background !**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.testedsg.MainActivity"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />
```

**Step 3: DEPLOY !**

result: why do I see the title bar with the white area underneath whilst the app is loading?? Crazyness!
It's actually incredibly annoying because the first activity that shows up has some animation on it and the white space hides the initial part of the animation.

Additionally, the more complicated the fragments, the longer the app takes to load and the longer I see the white area :-(

**Question**

Is there anything that can be done to get rid of the white whilst the app loads ? I want the user to see the app UI ASAP and I especially don't want the white to hide the initial part of the UI animation.

**Screenshot to illustrate the problem...**
[image: annoying white area during app loading]

**Screenshot of what I want to see ASAP...**
[image: after loading]

Comment: Do you ever see this white screen in your app, like main.xml or fragments.xml or etc

Comment: No, activity_main.xml shows `android:background="@android:color/black"` in the ViewPager and fragment_main.xml shows `android:background="@android:color/black"` in the RelativeLayout. Those are the only two layouts in the project.

Comment: I've noticed, since switching to Fragments, that this white area shows by default and actually shows longer and longer depending on the complexity of the fragments. I didn't notice this problem before using Fragments.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To fix this nasty problem, update the /res/values/styles.xml to include

- `<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>`

or

- `<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>`

for example :

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <!-- <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item> -->
</style>
```

Note: my entire app uses the `AppTheme` style (defined in the manifest). If you have a different theme just use either windowDisablePreview or windowBackground depending on the effect you prefer.

Comment: Does it work only for API Level > 10 or can I use it also for API Level 8? Because I see you specified `/res/values-v11/styles.xml`

Comment: oh - this actually goes into just /res/values/styles.com   (it was so late last night when I found this solution).

Comment: yeah, `windowDisablePreview` was added in API 3 and `windowBackground` has been around since the start. Hehe, I know what you mean by "luckily".